# Reading .md in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, markdown

I would like to `GET` the contents of an `.md` document as a string in my React Component. For some reason, my `XMLHttpRequest()` is logging my `index.html` file. Why would the following code be logging my `index.html` file and not my `my-first-article.md` file?

```
export default class Article extends React.Component {
  readTextFile = file => {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open('GET', file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
        if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
          var allText = rawFile.responseText;
          console.log(allText);
        }
      }
    };
    rawFile.send(null);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <article>
        {this.readTextFile('./data/posts/my-first-article.md')}
      </article>
    );
  }
}
```

If it is helpful, the relevant files in my directory are structured like so:

```
src/
  article.js
  data/
    posts/
      my-first-article.md
```

TY in advance.

Comment: can you access that file directly from the browser ?

Comment: I can open the file with my browser if I navigate to it with Mac's finder GUI. But if I try and ping the file's location from my local environment `//data/posts/my-first-article.md` I get a 'Your file was not found' error.

Comment: Then you should config your react app to serve static file then you can make the request to get it content

Answer (score 2):

Due to the asynchronous nature of web accesses, an asynchronous approach should be used. In this case the state of the components can be initialized in the constructor and after the result has received it will be set to the new value. When the state changes a new rendering of the component will be done automatically.

```js
export default class Article extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      content: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.readTextFile('./data/posts/my-first-article.md') 
  }

  readTextFile(file) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open('GET', file);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange =  () => {
      if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
        if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
          var allText = rawFile.responseText;
          this.setState({ content: allText });
        }
      }
    };
    rawFile.send(null);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <article>
        { this.state.content }
      </article>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I found a solution in the last thirty minutes, and my solution is very similar to what you've done here, leveraging state. The only key difference is that I've moved the `posts` directory into the `public` directory so that I can break out of React's module system by prefixing the file's path with `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`. You can read more about it here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder. I'll suggest an edit and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is **only** applicable if .md file is stored *locally*, however, as I understood later it's not mentioned explicitly in the question where the file is stored. The answer is left unchanged just in case someone will run into similar issue having the file stored locally.

React (according to its creators) is intended to be used for creating  the V (view) in MVC (model, view, controller) systems.

So, in the MVC model, the View is not supposed to interact directly with the data.

Meanwhile that's exactly what you're asking for since .md file is exactly the data.

So, the right approach would be to ask server to fetch local file for you & send it back.

Alternative approach would be to host .md somewhere, for example, on github and fetch it directly from there (using [github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/) in case of GitHub).